dominance order of conjugate partition

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n $ be two sets of non-strictly decreasing non-negative integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i = m > 0 $. Let $a_i'$ and $b_i'$ be defined as the count of indices $ k $where $ a_k \geq i $ and $b_k \geq i$ respectively. The problem requires proving that if 
$a_1' \geq b_1', \\
a_1' + a_2' \geq b_1' + b_2', \\
\vdots\\
a_1' + \ldots + a_m' \geq b_1' + \ldots + b_m'$
then
$b_1 \geq a_1, \\
b_1 + b_2 \geq a_1 + a_2, \\
\vdots\\
 b_1 + \ldots + b_n \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_n$

I prove it by induction, but I feel kind of weird. I believe there are some clever way to prove it. Can anyone help me out?\
For $m = 1 $, both $ a_i' $ and $ b_i' $ are either 0 or 1 because each $ a_i $ and $ b_i $ is non-negative and their sum is 1.
Given $ a_1' \geq b_1' $:
If $ a_1' = 1 $, then $ b_1' $ can be either 0 or 1.
If $ b_1' = 1 $, then $ a_1' $ must be 1.
Since $ a_1 $ and $ b_1 $ are non-negative integers and their sum is 1:
$ b_1 \geq a_1 $ holds trivially.
$ b_1 + b_2 \geq a_1 + a_2 $ holds because $ b_2 \geq a_2 $ (since $ b_1 = a_1  $ and $ b_1' + b_2' \geq a_1' + a_2' $).
Therefore, the base case holds.
Assume the statement is true for $ m = k $:
$b_1 \geq a_1, \quad b_1 + b_2 \geq a_1 + a_2, \quad \ldots, \quad b_1 + \ldots + b_k \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_k$
We need to prove it for $ m = k + 1 $:
Given $a_1' \geq b_1',, \ldots, a_1' + \ldots + a_k' \geq b_1' + \ldots + b_k' $, and $ a_1' + \ldots + a_{k+1}' \geq b_1' + \ldots + b_{k+1}' $, we want to show $b_1 + \ldots + b_{k+1} \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_{k+1} $.
Consider:
$b_1 + \ldots + b_k + b_{k+1} \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_k + a_{k+1} $
From the inductive hypothesis:
$b_1 + \ldots + b_k \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_k $
And since $ a_1' + \ldots + a_{k+1}' \geq b_1' + \ldots + b_{k+1}' $, it follows that $ b_{k+1} \geq a_{k+1} $.
Thus,
$b_1 + \ldots + b_{k+1} \geq a_1 + \ldots + a_k + a_{k+1} = a_1 + \ldots + a_{k+1} $
Therefore, by mathematical induction, the statement holds for all $ m \geq 1 $.
